# How to save a txt file that has columns to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I have a output from a terminal command that I used on python saved to a txt file. Then I need to save that txt file to a csv file.
the problem is when I write to csv file, all the content is written in one row.

**This is the code for the output:**

```
import subprocess
import csv


pl = subprocess.Popen(["snmptable", "-v2c", "-c", "public", "104.236.166.95",
                       "hrSWRunTable"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(pl.decode("utf-8"))
pll = pl.decode("utf-8")
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(pll)
text_file.close()

with open('Output.txt') as infile, open('coordv.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(" ".join(line.split()).replace(' ', ','))
        outfile.write(",")
```

**This is what I want to add to the csv:**

```
SNMP table: HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunTable

 hrSWRunIndex       hrSWRunName               hrSWRunID                                                        hrSWRunPath                                                                                                                  hrSWRunParameters hrSWRunType hrSWRunStatus
            1            "init" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                         "init [4]"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            2     "migration/0" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                      "migration/0"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            3     "ksoftirqd/0" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                      "ksoftirqd/0"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            4     "migration/1" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                      "migration/1"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            5     "ksoftirqd/1" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                      "ksoftirqd/1"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            6        "events/0" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                         "events/0"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            7        "events/1" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                         "events/1"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            8         "khelper" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                          "khelper"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
            9         "kthread" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                          "kthread"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
           87       "kblockd/0" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                        "kblockd/0"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
           88       "kblockd/1" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                        "kblockd/1"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
           89          "kacpid" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                           "kacpid"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
          184           "ata/0" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                            "ata/0"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
          185           "ata/1" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                            "ata/1"                                                                                                                                 "" application      runnable
          186         "ata_aux" SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero                                                          "ata_aux"
```

Comment: change `outfile.write(",")` to `outfile.write('\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write on a new line

```
# Write initial text
outfile.write(...)

# At end of first row, move to the next line
outfile.write('\n')
```

'\n' - This moves to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to import the `csv` module for csv writing, but not actually using it.

Take the file handle you created for writing and create a `csv.writer` out of it. Then, you can write rows with it; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

So, for your case:

```
with open('Output.txt') as infile, open('coordv.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for line in infile:
        writer.writerow(line.split())  # ... or whatever you'd need in the rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [output formats](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/TUT:Customized_Output_Formats) of net-snmp for easier and more reliable parsing.